# Deleting rows from a join of two tables and rownum condition in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, database, join, plsql, oracle11g

Learning PL/SQL with Oracle DB and trying to accomplish the following:

I have two tables a and b. I am joining them on id, add several conditions and then try removing resulting rows only from table a in a batch size of 1000. Base query looks like this:

```
DELETE (SELECT * 
        FROM SCHEMA.TABLEA a 
             INNER JOIN SCHEMA.TABLEB b ON a.b_id = b.id 
        WHERE par=0 AND ROWNUM <= 1000);
```

This obviously doesn’t work as I am trying to manipulate a view: “data manipulation operation not legal on this view”

How can I rewrite this?

Answer (score 1):

you can only remote from a table, there now Need to do a join. you can handle it in a where clause if you Need

you delete Statement could be e.g.

```
DELETE from SCHEMA.TABLEA a
where a.id in (select b.id from SCHEMA.TABLEB b)
and par=0 AND ROWNUM <= 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write simple query which checks if the rows in TABLEA that are required to be deleted exists in TABLEB.

```
DELETE
FROM schema.tablea a
WHERE par = 0
AND   EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM schema.tableb b WHERE a.b_id = b.id)
AND   rownum <= 1000;
```